# Issue with read-only embedded postgres DB using spring boot and flyway migrations

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, integration-testing, flyway, embedded-postgres

**Use case**
I am trying to have 2 datasources in my application. One for read-only connection and another for read-write connection.

**Configuration**
I have configured my JPA repositories to use different connections. In my IT case, I have the following configuration in my `application.yaml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/app
    username: postgres
    password:
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
```

**Issue in local build**

When I run the test in my local, the test fails while trying to create the `readOnlyDataSource` with the error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "app" does not exist
```

Where as when I change the DB url to `jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres`, the local test passes. Beans are getting created properly.

**Issue in CI build**

In CI build though, no matter the DB name as `app` or `postgres` , the test fails with

```
Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'readOnlyDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I have flyway migrations defined, and I can see in the logs that migrations ran successfully once with the primary read-write datasource. After created the read only connection, seeing the log `migrations are up to date`, so I think it didn't  try to run again using RO connection.

Also I have used `@Primary` on my read-write configuration, so that flyway knows to use that datasource for its migrations and not the read-only connection.

```
@Bean(name = ["primaryDataSource"])
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.configuration")
    fun primaryDataSource(dataSourceProperties: DataSourceProperties): HikariDataSource {
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource::class.java)
            .build()
    }
```

Is there any restrictions on having read-only connection with embedded postgres?

Comment: how is your CI configured? do you have postgres on CI system, or remote?

Comment: I found more information by running `mvn help:effective-pom` and figured that DB name comes from below properties
`<docker.postgres.alias>postgres</docker.postgres.alias>     <docker.postgres.env.POSTGRES_DB>app</docker.postgres.env.POSTGRES_DB>      <docker.postgres.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD>password</docker.postgres.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD>  <docker.postgres.env.POSTGRES_USER>app</docker.postgres.env.POSTGRES_USER>
      <docker.postgres.name>postgres:alpine</docker.postgres.name>
      <docker.postgres.wait.log>listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432</docker.postgres.wait.log>`